# Batch file to read data line by line from a file and use this data for further calculation

Tags: file, batch-file, abaqus

I have a  named filename.conf.
This file contains 3 lines. 
I want to use the data Line 1 for my First Abaqus job calculation (Job-1) , data in line 2 for second Abaqus Job (Job-2) , data in line 3 for third Abaqus job (Job-3)...
Can anyone help me with the batch file that will read the data from each line and use data for each Abaqus job calculation Respectively.

Here is the structure :-

```
filename.conf 
1  data1
2  data2
3  data3
```

The filename.conf cantains 3 lines as shown , how can I use data in 1st line for Job-1 Calculation , data in line 2 for Job-2 calculation , data in line 3 for Job-3 calculation.

Thanks in Advance.
ameyak1

Comment: the number in the file points to the job? Or just job numbers are iterated per line ?

Comment: line one just contains the name of the file that will be used ..so I have data in my directory with those 3 names form filename.conf .. so i need name in line 1 for Job-1 and so on

Comment: If you hover above the 'batch-file' tag, it says "A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on DOS, OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems."  So, are you sure you are talking about that kind of batch file?  (One with a `.bat` extension?)

Comment: Actually im running the batch file from a software called Hyperstudy and i give solver as Abaqus.Execute.bat

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a variable (`job1, job2,job3,jobx`) with each line 
you can use:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (filename.conf) do (
 set Job!$c!=%%a
 set /a $c+=1
)

echo Job1 = %job1%
echo Job2 = %job2%
echo Job3 = %Job3%
```

If you don't need to set variables (directly run the calculation with each line) :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (filename.conf) do call:calculate %%a
exit/b

:calculate
echo Working with %1
```